# Jsoup, how do I check if there is a <a> element?

Tags: java, html, csv, jsoup

I am currently trying to convert my Google Takeout from HTML to a CSV file, to save memory in the long run and to analyze this data. My code works, but only until an element shows up without a search term. Now I wanted to check if the element exists, but I couldn't do it :(

```java
public class HTMLtoCSV {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File input = new File("MeineAktivitäten.html");
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");

        int i = doc.getElementsByClass("outer-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-shadow--2dp").size();
        System.out.println("Titel = " + doc.title());
        System.out.println("Menge = " + i);

        File output = new File("output.csv");
        if(!output.exists()){
            output.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("output.csv", true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write("Type, Datum, Zeit, Suche, Link, Ort");
        bw.newLine();
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            String out1 = doc.getElementsByClass("header-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col").get(j).getElementsByClass("mdl-typography--title").text();
            // Test if tag "a" Exists

            String out2 = "";
            String out4 = "";
            // Test if tag "a" Exists when not dont use getElementsByTag
            if (doc.getElementsByClass("header-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col").get(j).getElementsByTag("a").size().) {
                 out2 = doc.getElementsByClass("content-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-typography--body-1").get(j).getElementsByTag("a").get(0).text();
                 out4 = doc.getElementsByClass("content-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-typography--body-1").get(j).getElementsByTag("a").get(0).attr("href");

            }
            String out3 = Objects.requireNonNull(doc.getElementsByClass("content-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-typography--body-1").get(j).getElementsByTag("br").get(0).nextSibling()).toString();
            String out5 = doc.getElementsByClass("content-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-typography--caption").get(j).getElementsByTag("a").get(0).attr("href");
            System.out.println("[Current Position: " + j + "/"+ i + "] " + out1 + ", " + out3 + ", \"" + out2 + "\", \"" + out4 + "\"" + ", \"" + out5 + "\"");
            bw.write(out1 + ", " + out3 + ", \"" + out2 + "\", \"" + out4 + "\"" + ", \"" + out5 + "\"");
            bw.newLine();

        }
        bw.close();
    }

}
```

My code is certainly not good, but it works (at least before I tried to exclude it with if). I have tried a few things myself, but have not succeeded. I hope that someone can help me here.
If it helps, Here is my imput:

```html
 <div class="outer-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-shadow--2dp">
        <div class="mdl-grid">
            <div class="header-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col"><p class="mdl-typography--title">Google Suche<br></p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-typography--body-1">Nach <a
                    href="https://www.google.com/search?q=Stone">Stone</a> gesucht<br>13.02.2022, 10:35:07
                MEZ
            </div>
            <div class="content-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-typography--body-1 mdl-typography--text-right"></div>
            <div class="content-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-typography--caption"><b>Produkte:</b><br>&emsp;Google
                Suche<br><b>Standorte:</b><br>&emsp;<a
                        href="http://GoogleMapsLinkHere">Ungefähre
                    Gegend</a> - Aus <a href="https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3184808">Meine Orte</a>
                (Zuhause)<br><b>Warum steht das hier?</b><br>&emsp;Diese Aktivität wurde in Ihrem Google-Konto
                gespeichert, weil die folgenden Einstellungen aktiviert waren:&nbsp;Web- &amp; App-Aktivitäten.&nbsp;<a
                        href="https://myaccount.google.com/activitycontrols">Hier können Sie diese Einstellungen
                    bearbeiten.</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Without the Tags:

```
<div class="outer-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-shadow--2dp">
        <div class="mdl-grid">
            <div class="header-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col"><p class="mdl-typography--title">Google Suche<br></p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-typography--body-1">Verwendet: Google Suche<br>12.02.2022,
                20:16:29 MEZ
            </div>
            <div class="content-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-typography--body-1 mdl-typography--text-right"></div>
            <div class="content-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-typography--caption"><b>Produkte:</b><br>&emsp;Google
                Suche<br><b>Warum steht das hier?</b><br>&emsp;Diese Aktivität wurde in Ihrem Google-Konto gespeichert,
                weil die folgenden Einstellungen aktiviert waren:&nbsp;Web- &amp; App-Aktivitäten.&nbsp;<a
                        href="https://myaccount.google.com/activitycontrols">Hier können Sie diese Einstellungen
                    bearbeiten.</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the wrong wrong class names are used in the `if` statement.

> change it to `content-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col`, and fix the syntax error in the if statement to be someting like:
>
> `...get(j).getElementsByTag("a").size() > 0`